# Create overflow in one div with height in percentages

Tags: html, css, angular, size

I'm creating a card header with an image as a background, but I want it to have overflow, I tried setting the height at 100 and max height at 70 percent, but didn't work, this is what I have, and I want it to make it in the same div, and if it is possible just to work with percentage

```css
.cartaCus {
    width: 92% !important;
    height: 90% !important;
}

.h90 {
    height: 90%;
}

.mapHeader {
    overflow: auto;
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 70%;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url(./../../../assets/images/backgrounds/map.png);
    background-color:red;
}
.w100 {
    width: 100%;
}
.alic {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.carta {
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 0px rgb(0 0 0 / 22%);
}
html,
body {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
    background-color: #dedede;
}
.h100 {
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="w100 h90">
    <div class="alic h100">
        <div class="carta cartaCus">
            <div class="mapHeader">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: You're using "background-image", so you have not a "div" with overflow. The "content" of the div (not the background) it's that makes overflow or not. BTW: check the "path" of the image. The path it's relative to root (should be simply `./assets/images/background/map.png`)

Comment: please explain in brief what you would like to achieve?

Comment: @Eliseo thanks by the comment, also by the angular structure that I am using, the path needs to be that way, I already tried the way that you are adding, but didnt work, ill try it again anyway

Comment: @HelpingHands I wanted that the div where I have the background has scroll and with it the the background moves, I alredy made the scroll, but the background is not moving anyway